# Program/app that can check permissions?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

Is there a program or app out there that you could place on a network location and run it to see if the currently logged in user has full control permissions to the file that you just placed there? Right now I can see what's in the Security tab, but it doesn't tell me exactly what group the user is in, etc. Has anyone heard of or seen something like this?

Comment: assuming from context - under windows? Security->Advanced->Effective permissions. There is no simple way of doing that via cmd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out a local users group memberships with

```
net user *username here*
```

At the network level

```
gpresult /USER *username here*
```

Replace *username here* with the username and no asterisks around it.

File permissions information

```
cacls *file path here*
```

Replace *file path here* with the file/directory name or path

Subinacl command from microsoft can show you some command line permissions ( http://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html)

Another tool xacls ( http://ss64.com/nt/xcacls.html)

Show owner of a file

```
dir /Q
```

I think some combination of these will help. Also, if you are on a more modern system I would check out the capabilities of powershell to address this problem over cmd. I will update if I can think of any other commands which may be helpful in your pursuits.